# Get multiple business images (image_url) from yelp api

Tags: yelp

Using the Yelp Business API, is it possible to get more than one business image?

According to the documentation, the json returns only one image:
http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business

Comment: *"According to the documentation, the json returns only one"* - then... no?

Comment: removed your language tags because you did not give any examples or mention the languages you tagged in your question.

Comment: Maybe I missed something and there is a trick to get multiple.

Answer (score 2):

There are several images available:

- image_url - URL of photo for this business
- snippet_image_url - URL of snippet image associated with this business
- deals.image_url - Deal image url
- gift_certificates.image_url - Gift certificate image url
- reviews.user.image_url - User profile image url
- others that I may have missed

So, yes, it is possible to get more than one image.

Of these image types, there could be multiple gift_certificate images (because `gift_certificates` is defined as a list). Similarly for `deals.image_url`. Reviews might in future, but is currently restricted to 1 review at present.

Comment: Is it possible to get multiple business images, like the one you get from image_url?

Comment: Well, as documented, no, there is only one.

Answer (score 0):

There is an end point called the "business API". According to the [documentation](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business) the JSON response to this end point contains a field called `photos` where you can access multiple pictures of the business in question. Hope this helped.